# Mis datos no se agregan a mysql, pero me dice que mi registro si se ah guardado y mi conexion es exitosa. ¿que puedo hacer?

Tags: php, mysql, css

Si pueden ayudarme se los agradeceria mucho ya que es mi primer tienda online y tengo este mismo problema con otras tablas más, sin embargo tengo otros formularios en la misma base y esos si me los almacena correctamente no se que es lo que pase con algunos archivos que nadamas no se agrega, ya me habia pasado antes pero solo era por que la conexion estaba mal, pero ahora ya me dice que esta correcta pero sigue sin agregarme nada. gracias
**conectar.php**
ESTE ES MI ARCHIVO DE CONECTAR

```
<?php
try {
    $Conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tienda_elgrano','root', '');
    echo "Conexion exitosa";
EL ECHO LO USO PARA VERIFICAR QUE SE CONECTE CORRECTAMENTE
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "¡Error!:".$e->getMessage()."<br>";
    die();
}
?>
```

EL REGISTRO ES PARA DESPUES PODER INICIAR SESION PERO NO PUEDO SABER SI ESAS SI ME FUNCIONAN BIEN YA QUE COMO DIGO NO PUEDO AGREGAR NADA, DESDE LA CONSOLA Y DESDE PHPMYADMIN SI, PERO ES CHISTE ES HACERLO DESDE EL SIGUENTE FORMULARIO

**Formulario.php**
ESTE ES EL FORMULARIO Y PARECE QUE TODO ES CORRECTO

```
<?php
    require('conectar.php');
?>
AQUI ESTA LA SUPUESTA CONEXION
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>REGÍSTRATE</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
                <form action="agregar_registro.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <p>Ingresa tu Nombre:</p>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" required="" placeholder="Nombre" class="form- control">
                    <BR>
                    <p>Ingresa tu Domicilio:</p>
                    <input type="text" name="domicilio" required="" placeholder="Domicilio" class="form-control">
                    <BR>
                    <p>Ingresa tu Telefono:</p>
                    <input type="number" name="telefono" required="" placeholder="Telefono" class="form-control">
                    <BR>
                    <p>Ingresa tu Usuario:</p>
                    <input type="text" name="usuario" required="" placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control">
                    <br>
                    <p>Ingresa tu foto de perfil:</p>
                    <input type="file" name="foto" required="" class="form-control">
                    <br>
                     <p>Ingresa tu Email:</p>
                    <input type="email" name="email" required="" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                    <br>
                     <p>Ingresa tu Contraseña:</p>
                    <input type="password" name="password" required="" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
                    <br>    
                    <p name="cbotipo_usuario" class="form-control" style="text-align: left;">Tipo de usuario:</p>
                    
                    <select name="cbotipo_usuario"  required="" class="form-control">
                        <option>Seleccione...</option>
                        <?php
ESTE CAMPO ESTA ASI PORQUE SE RELACIONA CON OTRA TABLA QUE SE LLAMA TIPO_USUARIO
                               $consulta = $Conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM tipo_usuario WHERE Id_tipo_usuario = 'TU4'");
                               $consulta->execute();
                               $resultado = $consulta->fetchAll();
                               foreach ($resultado as $fila) {
                                   echo '<option value="'.$fila['Id_usuario'].'">'.$fila['Nom_tipo_usuario'].'</option>';
                               }
                            ?>
                    </select>
                    
                    <br>
                            <input type="submit" name="" value="REGISTRARSE">
                            <a href="iniciar_sesion.php"><button class="btn btn-success">REGRESAR</button></a>
                </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**agregar_registro.php**
SUPONGO YO QUE AQUI ESTA EL ERROR PERO NO LO LOGRO ENCONTRAR A LA HORA DE AGREGAR LOS REGISTROS ME INDICA QUE SE HA GUARDADO PERO NI EN LA CONSOLA NI EN PHPMYADMIN APARECE NADA.

```
<?php 
    include('conectar.php');
    $nom = $_POST['nombre'];
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $dom = $_POST['domicilio'];
    $tel = $_POST['telefono'];

    $foto = $_FILES['foto'];


    $tmp_name = $foto['tmp_name'];
    $directorio_destino = "images";
    //ESTA ES LA CARPETA DESTINO
        $img_file = $foto['name'];
        $destino = $directorio_destino . '/' .  $img_file;
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $destino);

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    
ESTO LO USO PARA VERIFICAR QUE NO HAYA OTRO USUARIO, PASSWORD Y EMAIL IGUAL EN MI BASE DE DATOS
    $consulta = "SELECT USUARIO, Email, Password FROM Usuarios";
    $resultado = $Conexion->query($consulta);
                    while ($fila = $resultado->fetch())
                    {           
                        $verificar_usuario = $fila['USUARIO'];
                        $verificar_email =$fila['Email'];
                        $verificar_pass = $fila['Password'];      
                    }

    if ($usuario === $verificar_usuario OR $password == $verificar_pass OR $email == $verificar_email) {
        //echo "USUARIO existente";
        echo '<script language="javascript">alert("EL NOMBRE DE USUARIO, EL EMAIL Y/O PASSWORD YA ESTA EN USO");window.location.href="form_reg_login.php"</script>';
    }
    else
    {
        
        $tipo_usuario = $_POST['cbotipo_usuario'];


        $agregar = "INSERT INTO Usuarios(Id_usuario, NOMBRE, Domicilio, Telefono, USUARIO, FOTO, Email, Password, id_tipo_usuario) VALUES (NULL,'$nom','$dom','$tel','$usuario','$destino','$email','$password','$tipo_usuario')";
        $resultado = $Conexion->prepare($agregar);
        $resultado->execute();
ESTE IF ES EL QUE ME DICE QUE SE AH GUARDADO PERO EN REALIDAD NO SE GUARDA NADA
        if ($resultado) {
            echo "guardado";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "fallo la insercion";                   
        }
SIN EMBARGO LA FOTO SI SE GUARDA Y SE VA A LA CARPETA QUE LE ESTOY INDICANDO EN ESTE CASO IMAGES/
    }
?>
```

Comment: No me cuadra la consulta que realizas pues le fuerzas el `Id_tipo_usuario = "TU4"` y luego, en el **option** usas `<option value="'.$fila['Id_usuario'].'">` que aún entiendo menos.  Aparte de eso tienes mal el concepto de como usar sentencias `prepare` pues tal como las haces no estas escapando los valores, y en cuanto a la verificación de la contraseña no te recomiendo que lo hagas asi, aunque te esté funcionando. Pero eso son temas aparte. Primero revisa el `option` y la estructura de esa tabla a ver si ves lógico lo que haces y si los campos son correctos.

Comment: Hola. Si "Id_usuario" coincide con el id de la tabla y le asignas "NULL" no parece lógico... Por cierto, como te ha comentado masterguru, debes plantearte cambiar el método que usas para comprobar el usuario, etc.: por ejemplo, un usuario malicioso puede probar contraseñas hasta que le aparezca el aviso de "USUARIO existente". `if ($usuario === $verificar_usuario OR $password == $verificar_pass OR $email == $verificar_email) {
        //echo "USUARIO existente";`

Comment: Mastergutu eso lo hago para que en la lista desplegable me muestre el nombre del tipo de usuario y no el ID . ¿Cómo debo de usar prepare? Puedo usar include?

Comment: Mírate la sintaxis del prepare en este enlace directo a la [documentación oficial de php](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php#refsect1-pdo.prepare-examples). Veras que los valores pasados no los ponen en la consulta SQL sino en el execute, por que así los valores son verificados escapandose en tiempo de ejecución y asi evitar problemas de inyección en SQL.

Comment: En cuanto a la lista desplegable, necesito saber las columnas de la estructura de la tabla "tipo_usuario" porque creo que lo haces mal, pero no puedo estar seguro si no la veo.

Comment: Y eso del include ni idea a lo que te refieres... ¿como lo usarias? ¿y para incluir que?

Comment: ```                                                                                                 
 CREATE TABLE Tipo_Usuario (
Id_tipo_usuario VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Nom_tipo_usuario VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
```                                                                                                      
ESTOS SON LOS VALORES QUE TENGO AGREGADOS
insert into Tipo_usuario values ('TU1','ADMINISTRADOR');
insert into Tipo_usuario values ('TU2','PROVEEDOR');
insert into Tipo_usuario values ('TU3','EMPLEADO');
insert into Tipo_usuario values ('TU4','CLIENTE');

Comment: Mirate la nueva respuesta de @triby y segun deduzco por lo que veo en tu tabla `tipo_usuario` veo un error claro en `formulario.php` pues esta consulta entonces no tiene sentido: `SELECT * FROM tipo_usuario WHERE Id_tipo_usuario = 'TU4'` pues solo te generara un `<option>` donde ademas le pones mal su valor. En lugar de `value="'.$fila['Id_usuario'].'"` debes poner `value="'.$fila['Id_tipo_usuario'].'"` para que le ponga un `TU4` en lugar de nada (`$fila['Id_usuario']` no existe en esa consulta)

Comment: @masterguru muchas gracias ya veo el error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes algunos errore de lógica y otros de programación:

1. Debes manipular el archivo después de verificar que el usuario no está repetido.
2. No es recomendable evitar contraseñas duplicadas, solo nombre de usuario y correo electrónico deben ser únicos.
3. Estás leyendo y recorriendo toda la tabla de usuarios para verificar si el usuario o correo electrónico ya están registrados. Aparte de que no es óptimo, en el ciclo estás sobrescribiendo las variables en cada iteración y deberías finalizar en cuanto se encuentre un registro duplicado, de lo contrario, la validación no funcionará correctamente, a menos que el duplicado se encuentre en la última posición.
4. En lugar de leer toda la tabla, cuenta los registros duplicados. Para este ejemplo, se buscan usuario y correo electrónico juntos, pero lo ideal es que los compruebes por separado, para que puedas decirle al usuario cuál dato es incorrecto.
5. Al revisar si se pudo insertar, deberías usar otra variable o, directamente comparar si `$resultado->execute()` devolvió verdadero, como lo estás haciendo ahora siempre va a ser verdadero, porque `$resultado` es un recurso de acceso a base de datos, diferente de NULL y de falso.

Ya que estás usando PDO, es conveniente hacer las consultas preparadas para minimizar errores y riesgo de inyección SQL. La forma más fácil es con marcas de remplazo `?` y proporcionar los valores en un arreglo al ejecutar.

Adicionalmente, no es conveniente guardar las contraseñas tal como las tecleó el usuario, eso facilita la labor de los hackers/crackers para acceder a tu sitio. Te recomiendo investigar sobre [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash) para guardar la contraseña y [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify) para comparar al iniciar sesión.

```
<?php
include('conectar.php');
// Obtén todos los datos desde el inicio
$nom = $_POST['nombre'];
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$dom = $_POST['domicilio'];
$tel = $_POST['telefono'];
$tipo_usuario = $_POST['cbotipo_usuario'];

// Primero verifica que no existe el usuario o correo
// Contando, en lugar de leer todos los registros
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as registrado FROM usuarios WHERE USUARIO = ? OR Email = ?';
// Prepara la consulta
$res = $Conexion->prepare($sql);
// Envía un arreglo con los valores para remplazar los ?
$res->execute([$usuario, $email]);
$datos = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// Verificar el contador
if($datos['registrado'] > 0) {
    // El nombre de usuario o correo electrónico ya están usados
} else {
    // Se puede continuar, ahora sí es momento de mover el archivo
    $foto = $_FILES['foto'];
    $tmp_name = $foto['tmp_name'];
    $directorio_destino = "images";
    // ESTA ES LA CARPETA DESTINO
    $img_file = $foto['name'];
    $destino = $directorio_destino . '/' .  $img_file;
    // Continuar solo si el archivo se pudo mover
    if(!move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $destino)) {
        // Error moviendo archivo
    } else {
        // El archivo se movió correctamente a su ubicación final
        // Ahora sí puedes insertar
        $agregar = 'INSERT INTO Usuarios (NOMBRE, Domicilio, Telefono, USUARIO, FOTO, Email, Password, id_tipo_usuario) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
        $res = $Conexion->prepare($agregar);
        // Ejecuta la consulta enviando los valores en un arreglo
        $exito = $res->execute([$nom, $dom, $tel, $usuario, $destino, $email, $password, $tipo_usuario]);
        if($exito) {
            echo 'Guardado';
        } else {
            echo 'Falló la inserción';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias ya me funciona correctamente

Answer (score 0):

```
$agregar = "INSERT INTO Usuarios (Id_usuario, NOMBRE, Domicilio, Telefono, USUARIO, FOTO, Email, Password, id_tipo_usuario) 
VALUES (NULL,'$nom','$dom','$tel','$usuario','$destino','$email','$password','$tipo_usuario')";
$resultado = $Conexion->prepare($agregar);
$resultado->execute();
if ($resultado) {
   echo "guardado";
}else{
   echo "fallo la insercion";                   
}
```

Si esta es la sección que falla, debes revisarla enteramente.

Primero que nada, agrega un `echo` para mostrar `$agregar` y ver si la consulta funciona.
Segundo, no es necesario que mandes el `Id_usuario` como NULL, si es auto_incremental en la base de datos, se añadirá solo.
Tercero, la parte del IF puedes resumirla mucho más, prueba con:

```
echo ($resultado) ? "guardado" : "falló la inserción";
evaluamos $resultado ? true(guardado) : false(falló)
```

Comment: me di cuenta gracias al echo que mi dato de id_tipo_usuario no se refleja en el registro, sin embargo me dice "guardado" pero no se registra nada en la base de datos, ¿que puedo hacer?

Comment: La variable `$resultado` es una instancia de [PDOStatement](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.pdostatement.php) y, a menos que contenga uno de los valores [falsy](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting), esa comparación siempre será verdadera.